# Apache2 mod_rewrite redirection of SSL to non-SSL and vice versa based on URI matching

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I'm trying to make customer facing pages only available using non-SSL URIs. i.e. `http://domain.com/customerpage` where `customerpage` is some dynamic URI only known the underlying webapp.

The control panel for the administrator is kept in `/admin/controllername/action`  where `controllername` and `action` are various different controllers.  All admin requests are routed under the `/admin` portion of the URI.

I want ensure that if a user visits `https://domain.com/customerpage` they are redirected to `http://domain.com/customerpage`.

However, I also want to ensure that if an admin tries `http://domain.com/admin/login` or anything under `/admin` they are redirected to the secure `https://domain.com/admin/login` page.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: The problem is customer page is not a single page.  I used customer page to represent all other links that aren't admin

Comment: i have edited my answer, reload the page to see it, and let me know how it works